# Episerver WithAndAsDefaultOperator() does not work as expected with UsingSynonyms()

Tags: episerver, episerver-find

I have created a 'one way' synonym as “dog” > "animal”.

- When I search for "test+dog" it gives many results. (Which is as
  expected)
- When I search for **"dog+test"** it gives **0** results. **(Which is
  not as expected)**

**The above both queries should return the same result set (Many results) regardless of the word order.**

My search implementation is like below,

```
search = search.For(queryText) 
        .InAllField() 
        .WithAndAsDefaultOperator() 
        .UsingSynonyms();
```

This issue is not reproducible when,

- we remove the synonyms defined.
- we remove the WithAndAsDefaultOperator() or the UsingSynonyms().

This means there is an incompatibility/issue with the UsingSynonyms() when used along with the WithAndAsDefaultOperator().

Is this a known issue ?

*Note: I have found that there is an issue with multi-words synonyms and the WithAndAsDefaultOperator. But in my case, it is not about multi-word synonyms. But I do not know whether my issue is happening because of the same issue which fuels the multi-words synonyms issue.*

*My Episerver Find version is 13.2.x*

Thanks.

Comment: Is the value of `queryText` literally "test+dog"?

Comment: Yes. The value of the `queryText` is "test+dog" including the '+' but without the quotations ("").